# Calcular valor checkbox JS

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um formulário em html onde tenho que apresentar um total de acordo com os "extras selecionados", que são as checkbox.

Este código que tenho acrescenta a diferença entre as opções, ou seja, se o preço for 30 e acrescentar uma opção de 10 resulta 40, mas se por cima dessa de 10 acrescentar uma de 15, o total fica 45.

Se poderem ajudar agradeço, foi uma explicação confusa mas acho que dá para perceber mais ou menos, obrigado!

```js
let total = 0;
let check = document.getElementsByClassName("check");

for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

  if(check[i].checked) {
       total = (dias * viatura) + (check[i].value * 1) + "€";
       console.log(total);
   }
}

document.getElementById("total").value = total;
```

Comment: Favor [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o HTML referente ao JS para formar um [mcve] e explique qual é o problema e apresente o log de erros.

Answer (score 0):

Ok pelo que percebi da pergunta penso que isto possa ajuda:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function total() {
    let total = 0;
    let dias = 2;
    let viaturas = 2;
    let check = document.getElementsByName("checkbox");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
        if (check[i].checked) {
        total += parseInt(dias * viaturas) + parseInt(check[i].value);
        }
    }
    console.log(total + "€");
    }
</script>
```

Os problemas que reparei no teu script foi, não estares a acumular os totais, estavas sempre atribuir um novo valor à variável total e não a acumular.
Outro era em vez de estares a fazer uma conta e uma concatenação ao mesmo tempo, o que não funciona.
Ah e também atribui o máximo do ciclo for ao tamanho da variável em vez de um número fixo, ajuda com que o código fique mais dinâmico e se quiseres adicionar novas checkboxes não tenhas que estar sempre a alterar isso.

A função é chamada nas checkboxes com um evento onclick:

```
<input name="checkbox" value="5" type="checkbox" onclick="total()" />
```

Nota: Atribui valores fixos aos dias e viaturas para testar, espero que tenha ajudado :)